# Both MAP_ANON and MAP_ANONYMOUS undeclared for sys/mmap in C

Tags: c, unix, memory

This is my `mman.h` file included from `/usr/include/sys/`:

http://pastebin.com/FZpHwKMC

Somehow `mmap()` seems to be defined (and can be used with flags 0 and read/write protection), but not `MAP_ANON` **or** `MAP_ANONYMOUS` as indicated below:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

int a = MAP_ANON; /* compile error */
int b = MAP_ANONYMOUS; /* also compile error */
```

I'm at a loss of what could be wrong. I'm compiling using this makefile:

http://pastebin.com/R1V2edmf

EDIT: It turns out the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` macro is defined in `/usr/include/bits/mman.h` but **only** if `__USE_MISC` is defined...

Any help would be terrific!

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: On my linux box, those defines are in `/usr/include/bits/mman.h` which is included by your sys/mman.h header file.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I checked that file out, and edited my post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MAP\_ANONYMOUS with C99 standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446698/map-anonymous-with-c99-standard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using GCC, a common reason for this to occur is that you're not using a GNU C standard. Try compiling with, e.g., `-std=gnu11`, and see if that fixes the problem.

More information about GCC's language standards can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html).

GCC also provides a very exhaustive list of exactly what extensions they provide [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions).

Also, as a side note, it's preferrable to use `MAP_ANONYMOUS` instead of `MAP_ANON`, as the latter is deprecated (according to `man mmap`).

Comment: Thanks! Will try to compile with this flag, and see if it helps. I've edited my post.

Comment: Yeah, this is it.  The ANON options are not portable outside of the gnu compiler suite, so you have to have at least -std=gnu89 at minimum.  Interestingly, on my AIX and HPUX boxes, the options are there by default in the IBM and HP compilers....

Comment: Glad to help. :) I actually had this same problem earlier today.

Comment: The mmap() manpage suggests that _GNU_SOURCE is more than enough to solve the problem.