# mmap error on linux (using somethingelse)

Tags: c, linux, mmap, fork

Exactly, I thought that I finished my project until compiling isn't accepted on ubuntu because of `mmap()`. I'm trying to access(read) files by using `fork()`. It's okey. But, When I want to count number of read files, entered folder(directories) and child, I powned! How and What can I use or change `mmap()` because I get `error: ‘MAP_ANON’ undeclared (first use in this function)|`
. On mac, It's okey but on ubuntu error. Thank you for helps.

```
    #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
    #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <ftw.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <sys/mman.h>



    #define MAX_PATH_LEN        2048


    static int *wordCount = 0;
    static int *childCount = 0;
    static int *folderCount = 0;



    int relatedWord(const char *arr);

    int checkWord(const char arr[], int size);

    void err_sys(const char *msg);

    int disp(const char *filepath, const struct stat *finfo, int flag, struct FTW *ftw);


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        //struct stat finfo;

        //int count = 0;

        wordCount = mmap(NULL, sizeof *wordCount, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
        childCount = mmap(NULL, sizeof *childCount, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
        folderCount = mmap(NULL, sizeof *folderCount, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

        if (argc != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of arguments!\nUsage: dirwalk6 <path>\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (nftw(argv[1], disp, 20, 0) < 0)
            err_sys("ntfw");

        printf( "\nTotal words = %d\n\n", *wordCount);
        printf( "\nTotal folders = %d\n\n", *folderCount);
        printf( "\nTotal childs = %d\n\n", *childCount);


        return 0;
    }

int disp(const char *filepath, const struct stat *finfo, int flag, struct FTW *ftw)
{

    int count = 0; /* number of words */

    switch (flag) {
        case FTW_F: /* determining file */

            printf("%*s%s\n", ftw->level * 4, "", filepath);

            pid_t pid;

            pid=fork();

            if(pid < 0)
            {
                perror("Error corresponding to fork()");
            }
            else if (pid == 0)
            {

                count += relatedWord(filepath);
                *wordCount += count;
                *childCount += 1;
                exit(1);

            }
            else
            {
                while( pid != wait(0) ) ;
            }
            // printf( "word = %d,   file = %s \n", count,filepath);

            break;
        case FTW_D:  /* determining folder */
            printf("%*s%s\n", ftw->level * 4, "", filepath + ftw->base);
            *folderCount += 1;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Both MAP\_ANON and MAP\_ANONYMOUS undeclared for sys/mmap in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817309/both-map-anon-and-map-anonymous-undeclared-for-sys-mmap-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page for `mmap(2)` (my bold):

> Certain  flags  constants  are defined only if either `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_SVID_SOURCE` is defined.  (Requiring `_GNU_SOURCE` also suffices, and requiring that macro specifically would have been more logical, since these flags are all Linux specific.)  The relevant flags are: `MAP_32BIT`, `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (**and the synonym `MAP_ANON`**), `MAP_DENYWRITE`, `MAP_EXECUTABLE`, `MAP_FILE`, `MAP_GROWSDOWN`, `MAP_HUGETLB`, `MAP_LOCKED`, `MAP_NONBLOCK`, `MAP_NORESERVE`, `MAP_POPULATE`, and `MAP_STACK`.

So you will need to define `_BSD_SOURCE`, `_SVID_SOURCE` or (if I read that right) `_GNU_SOURCE` at the top of the file, but in any event prior to

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
```

As per @mafso's comment, best to do this prior to any system header include (not least in case an another header itself includes `<sys/mman.h>`

Comment: Prior to _any_ system header include.

Comment: @mafso - indeed, fixed.

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking, but it's not only if some other header includes `<sys/mman.h>` (I believe, system header aren't even allowed to do that). Every system header on my GNU system, for example, includes `<features.h>` to set the proper flags depending on macros defined. This header has header guards, so any later definition of a feature test macro will have no effect, as the header isn't included twice.