# `MAP_ANONYMOUS` undefined in visual studio 2019 with windows subsystem for linux

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS for my Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) (setup for WSL was done following this [MS dev post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/)), and even with my Visual Studio's project

```
Configuration Properties > General 
> Platform Toolset = GCC for Windows Subsystem for Linux
```

I get

> Identifier "MAP_ANONYMOUS" is undefined

with a program such as

```
int main() {
  int N = 5;
  int* ptr = mmap(NULL, N * sizeof(int),
      PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
}
```

Only `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is undefined, how can I fix this? I have tried changing the C language standard by going to my VS project's

```
Configuration Properties > C/C++ 
> All Options > C Language Standard = C11 (-std=gnu11)
```

per the recommendation of this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817309/both-map-anon-and-map-anonymous-undeclared-for-sys-mmap-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I posted this question, I found the solution. The solution is to set the C Language Standard *correctly* by doing

```
Configuration Properties > C/C++ 
> All Options > C Language Standard = C11(GNU Dialect)(-std=gnu11)
```

This can be selected using the C Language Standard drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS Code, just go to the configuration settings under where you see the c version and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djhih.png). Choose gnu11 and c++11 on the option underneath. This should automatically clear the error.